# Calculate the all the possible difference between elements of a list in an optimized way

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, nested-lists

I have a list of lists, for example [[0], [1, 1], [4, 2, 4], ...]. I want to iterate through each individual nested list and build a new list of lists that contains all the signed differences between values within each specific list. For this example list, the resulting list of lists would be:

differences = [[0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, -2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0],....]

I have already implemented a brute-force method which contains three nested `for` loops. The first `for` loop iterates through all the lists and the other two `for` loops iterate over a specific list to get all the possible differences.

I was wondering if someone can come up with a more optimized algorithm that runs faster? Thanks!

Comment: There are some possible minor optimizations using the facts that `a-a == 0` and `a-b == -(b-a)` but I think the runtime complexity for a single inner list with *n* items can't be reduced below *O(n²)*.

Comment: @MichaelButscher It can't be reduced below O(n²) for a very simple reason: those numbers need to be at least created and written in memory; and the length of the result is indeed O(n²)!

Comment: One of my ideas (but challenging to implement) is to reduce the number of redundant calculations. For example, consider an even-length list like [9, 5, 5, 9].  All possible differences could be thought of as a graph like this

`[0, 4, 4, 0],
[-4, 0, 0, -4],
[-4, 0, 0, 4], 
[0, 4, 4, 0]`

If you calculate the top-left portion of this graph, including some trivial calculations, we can automatically get the rest of the differences.

Comment: Anyway, this has been a real head-scratcher for me. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @SaifAli As I mentioned in my comment, you can't do better than a brute force algorithm here. Because you need to perform at least one operation (i.e., write the number to memory) per element of the final list. So you can maybe expect some very small O(1) improvements, but nothing more

Answer (score 0):

As clearly pointed out in the comments, you cannot go below `O(n^2)` for a `n` element sublist. However, you can be a little bit efficient, as you suggested to only do `n(n-1) / 2` subtractions.

Here's the formalization of your idea:

Take a sublist `L = [a,b,c]` of size `n = 3`

Consider a matrix A of size `n X n` to store the differences. Then clearly

```
A = |a-a  a-b  a-c| = |   0      a-b   a-c|
    |b-a  b-b  b-c|   |-(a-b)     0    b-c|
    |c-a  c-b  c-c|   |-(a-c)  -(b-c)   0 |
```

You can just compute the upper triangle having `n(n-1) / 2` entries. Diagonals are all 0's. The lower triangle values can be filled from the upper one, since `A` is skew-symmetric.

Last but not least, you serialize `A` in row-major order to get your desired 'difference list' `D`. Note that the entry `a_{i,j}` will be placed at the `i*n + j`-th place in `D`. [I have assumed 0 based indexing like in C.]